# JS object toString() returns constructor.name and data which I cannot retrieve in any other way

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My question is Adobe JS specific but I am almost sure its relevance is more general.

To begin, please consider the particular case:
Adobe JS API for 3D has an object called Matrix4x4. In the API Reference, I can read about its 5 properties: determinant, inverse, scaleComponent, translation and transpose.

In my code, I have one Matrix4x4 object.
Running "for (var i in Matrix4x4)", I just get the aforementioned properties. So Matrix4x4[i], might be the inverse matrix for example.

However, Matrix4x4.toString() gives back exactly the original matrix values I need but in the following string format:

Matrix4x4: 
(1, 0, 0, 0), 
(0, 1, 0, 0), 
(0, 0, 1, 0), 
(0, 0, 0, 1)

Matrix4x4.toSource() strangely gives ({}) i.e. an empty object.

Now, I aim to write a function or prototype to get the values of the matrix as .toString() does but without the heading "Matrix4x4:" (note Matrix4x4 is equal to constructor.name) and no line feeds (return carriages). I tried to use eval(Matrix4x4.toString()), eval("{"+Matrix4x4.toString()+"}") or eval("({"+Matrix4x4.toString()+"})") but it seems the string is not well formed. I suppose there should be two ' to enclose the matrix values and no line feeds.

Is it possible to either override .toString() method or write a custom prototype to retrieve those same values printed by the present .toString() in a such a strange format which is actually very close to a literal object?

As said, I have not succeeded in reaching the object values given back by .toString() in any other way but they must be somewhere inside the object because .toString() shows them and I think they are the arguments of all other properties. For example, .determinant is almost certainly calculated on them.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply use toString().slice(11); or something like that to extract the interesting values from what toString() returns ?

Comment: You make a good point but I am really disappointed .toString() gives exactly what I am looking for but there's no other way to ask the object to do in a better format. String manipulation here means I need to cut off all line feeds, parenthesis, commas and said constructor.name; the result is very bad code.

Comment: Could you link to those docs please? I don't believe there's no other way than `toString` to get the components.

Comment: @Bergi: sure it is http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_3d_api_reference.pdf (see page 40) and please have a look at this one too: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5516741#5516741 and linked http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1210295?tstart=0. I guess the solution lays in this last one. However, as said, Matrix4x4.toString() already provides all values needed that unfortunately need string manipulation.

Comment: From the below discussion with HMR, I conclude that object prototypes are very useful just when one has the corresponding constructor and therefore ideally when one has created the object himself.

Comment: Hm, OK. The actionscript implementation HMR pointed to has lots of setters and getter for `m00` through `m33` - maybe they just forgot them in the docs, and they're not enumerable?

Comment: @Bergi: if they were not enumerable, how could I invoke them?

Comment: @vooorka: Just by accessing them. They would exist, but be ignored by `for in`. You could also try `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(yourMatrixInstance))`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, you say you want a string but to trying to use eval to create an object. Maybe this will do the trick:

```
Matrix4x4.prototype.toObject=function(){
 return{
   determinant:this.determinant,
   inverse:this.inverse,
   scaleComponent:this.scaleComponent,
   translation:this.translation.
   transpose:this.transpose
 };
}
```

If you're trying to clone the object than it gets a bit more complicated. You can have a look at jQuery.extend (use it or use how they implement it in your own code).

Note that adding to the prototype will break (add it to) `for (var i in Matrix4x4)` unless you change some of the code:

```
for (var i in m44){
 if(m44.hasOwnProperty(i)){
   console.log(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: I would like to retrieve from the object the same info as .toString() now returns in my own format. If I were able to create an object out of the result of the present .toString(), I could use "var my_string = Obj.Matrix4x4;" and this would put only the matrix numbers into my_string. I don't think your prototype will solve the problem because all those methods already work but I don't need their results. I need the inner object values those same methods work on to calculate their results.

Comment: @vooorka So you want a string, if you override the toString or create a toMyBetterString() method on the prototype to return the string, will that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes HMR! And here comes the "pure" JS part: how do I override .toString if I don't know how it is now. I mean, .toString() now is working somehow but how? What its arguments? If I knew this part, I could even create my own "returnMatrix(i,j)" in a second stage.

Comment: @vooorka use `Matrix4x4.prototype.toString=function()`  or `Matrix4x4.prototype.myToString=function()` and implement it returning a string, I found the source code for Matrix4x4 as action script but the JavaScript implementation would not be much different: https://github.com/graysonlang/proscenium/blob/master/code/Proscenium/src/com/adobe/math/Matrix4x4.as

Comment: HMR, great stuff! Sorry to bother you again. I still find it difficult to understand how you would implement such a myToString prototype: it seems to me that _00 to _33 are my matrix numbers but they are private var. In JS, if I code in my prototype: "return _00" or "return this._00" I think I don't get it. Could you just code or pseudocode a myToString example for just one matrix element? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @vooorka Not sure if you can actually extend the Matrix4x4 and if there is a JavaScript equivilant for it. If there is a JS file that defines Matrix4x4 and they didn't implement private variables through closures you can override or implement your own kind of a toString method accessing the variables (JS doesn't have private variables but can simulate them through closures). Sadly I don't know anything about these libraries so not sure how you would go about doing it (maybe even hacking in the library action script files?)

Comment: @vooorka Not sure if the script would run in a browser, you could console.log the value of `this` in chrome and inspect it's properties. Or you can jump into the code of the constructor and see where Matrix4x4 is defined so you can implent your own toMyString methon in there.

Comment: thanks for your effort! However, I don't see how those matrix numbers are printed by .toString(). Using Acrobat console:

console.println("Matrix: "+ myMatrix.constructor)

returns:
Matrix:
function ScriptProxy() {
    [native code]
}